# getting a parameter from a list or an html parser using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, google-search

I am trying to get the suggested google word by inputting a wrongly spelled word:

Below is my code: Input : `Johnny walker rd lbl` Output:`Johnny walker red label`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
key = "Johnny walker rd lbl"
query = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + key
r = requests.get(query)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
#for s in soup.find_all(id="rhs_block"):
 #   pprint(s.text)
find=soup.find_all('script',attrs={'type':'text/javascript'})
mylist = []
for x in find:
    mylist.append(str(x.string))
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['None', "(function(){var eventid='QO7rW5TtM5OYvQT516NY';google.kEI = 
eventid;})();", 'google.ac&&google.ac.c({"agen":true,"cgen":true,
"client":"heirloom-serp","dh":true,"dhqt":true,"ds":"","ffql":"en","fl":true,"host":"google.com","isbh":28,"jsonp":true,
"msgs":{"cibl":"Clear Search","dym":"Did you mean:","lcky":"I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky","lml":"Learn more",
"oskt":"Input tools","psrc":"This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href=\\"/history\\"\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E","psrl":"Remove",
"sbit":"Search by image","srch":"Google Search"},"ovr":{},"pq":"Johnny walker red label","refpd":true,"rfs":[],"sbpl":24,"sbpr":24,"scd":10,"sce":5,"stok":"7UqfdDr4nbKtZNfvytsBW8kPB9E","uhde":false})']
```

how should I get just the "pq" tag from the available list of output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex

```
import re

....
html_doc = r.text
output = re.search(r'"pq":"([^"]+)', html_doc).group(1)
```

Comment: excellent, thanks, didnot think we can implement regex in html parsing. Working with bs4 for the first time. Thanks @ewwink

Comment: I am trying to generate results under a for loop and save it as a list, however unable to do it, every letter comes as a list item. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: are you doing `myList = [] ... for ... myList.append(output)` ?

Comment: forget it, i just discovered i had defined the list inside for loop. :p Need a break I guess, it works. :)